# how to style the variable on JS without DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm about to style the "newResult" with green if passed and red if failed. I'm confused how to style them since the "newResult" is not DOM.

```
@param {string} idIn

function checkId(idIn) { 
  let isIDin = false;
  let regexID = /^n|N[0-9]{8}$/i;

  if (regexID.test(idIn)) {
      isIDin = true;
  }
   return isIDin;
}

function test__checkId(valueIn, expected){
   let result = checkId(valueIn);
   var newResult;

//Print out value we are testing, and result of the function, and our expectation.
   if (result){
    newResult="==PASSED==";
   } else {
    newResult="XXFAILEDXX";
   }

let msg = "Value tested: " + valueIn + " | Expected result: " + expected + " " + newResult + "<br />";

 document.getElementById("data").innerHTML+=msg;
} 

//TIME TO RUN OUR UNIT TEST FUNCTION ON OUR checkHumberID FUNCTION...
test__checkId("n99999999",true); //boundary testing
test__checkId("n00000000",true); //boundary testing
test__checkId("ASFASDF",true); //boundary testing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of JavaScript template literals, ternary/conditional operator and inline CSS to accomplish what you're looking for.

The syntax might look confusing at first look, but it does the job.

```
let msg = "" ;
msg+=`Value tested:"${valueIn}" | Expected result:"${expected}" "${newResult == "==PASSED==" ? "<span style='color:green ;font-weight:bold'>==PASSED==</span>":"<span style='color:red ;font-weight:bold'>XXFAILEDXX</span>"} <br>` ;
                                                                                                         
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML+=msg;
```

[image: OutPut]

[image: VS code picture]

Answer (score 0):

You're building an HTML string, so it's simple enough to wrap `newResult` in a `span` with a class to set its color using CSS.

```
let msg = "Value tested: " + valueIn + " | Expected result: " + expected + " <span class='" + (result ? "pass" : "fail") + "'>" + newResult + "</span><br />";
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
```

Then add the styling for `.pass` and `.fail` to your CSS.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM represents an HTML document in memory. MDN's [Introduction to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction#dom_and_javascript) clarifies:

> The DOM is not part of the JavaScript language, but is instead a Web
> API used to build websites. JavaScript can also be used in other
> contexts. For example, Node.js runs JavaScript programs on a computer,
> but provides a different set of APIs, and the DOM API is not a core
> part of the Node.js runtime.

The DOM APIs are baked in to browsers whereas add-on packages are available for nodejs.

Once you have the DOM API's available, it's simply a matter of creating whatever elements you want in memory like `document.createElement("div");` then you add them to your HTLM document whenever you want using methods like `.appendChild`.

Comment: The OP is **already** building an HTML string and assigning it to a DOM element's `innerHTML`. While `createElement` works, it's awkward to combine with what they're doing. If you want them to completely change their approach, I suggest showing them how. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the king speaks! i guess i always avoid building strings in favor of utilizing the DOM API's? But, i'm sure you're right. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of using HTML strings either, but it's like swimming against the tide. :-) Sometimes I just say "Here's how you do it the way you're doing it."